# Issues with OneToOne field

Tags: django, django-models

When I syncdb my database I am getting the error of **module' object has no attribute 'OneToOnefield'**

The code of models.py is as :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
class Drinker(models.Model):
       user     =models.OneToOnefield(User)
       birthday =models.Datefield()
       name     =models.Charfield(max_length=100)


#create our user object to attach to our drinker object

def create_drinker_user_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
       drinker.new=Drinker.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_drinker_user_callback, User)
```

Comment: `drinker.new=Drinker.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)` this needs to be `drinker,new=Drinker.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `models.OneToOneField` i.e. Field with capital 'F'. That is issue with your other field definitions as well.